# Updating Codename one in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, codenameone

I can't seem to get ToastBar in my build, my CodenameOne.jar doesn't have the class. I've tried updating libs from project properties and it says it's all up to date. My eclipse says I have Codename 3.1 installed too, shouldn't it be 3.3 now? Is there something in particular I need to do to get the latest Codename one jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That API wasn't released yet and is only available in the source code at this time. It will be available within a couple of weeks as we try to release every 3-4 weeks.

The plugin version is a different thing from the lib version, you can update the libraries within the project to the latest version by pressing the "Update Project Libs" button in the Codename One section in the project preferences:

[image: Update Project Libs]

BTW Don't confuse Update Project Libs with Refresh Libs which is a completely different thing.

Comment: Great thanks. So once it's released, the "Update Project Libs" will do that?

Comment: Yes. Also sending a build to the build server will automatically update the libs so if you are sending builds this should "just work".