# Codename One Recover Project

Tags: codenameone, project

I am having an Android app that I developed in July 2019 using Eclipse (at least that is what the folder says).

Now I want to make some changes and tried to import and run the project with Eclipse.

But when trying to run the project, I get the following error messages:

```
These values are required!

userName - login information from codenameone.com
password - the password matching your login from codenameone.com
jarFile - the application jar file resulting from the build
ApplicationDisplayName - display name for the application in the UI
MainClassName - the name of the main class not including the package name
ApplicationPackageName - the package in which the main class resides, this will also be used to classify the application. It is recommended you give this some thought since package names are impossible to change later on some stores!
version - the version number for the application
```

There is some other strange behaviour, like the error:

```
The method getAllStyles() is undefined for the type Form
```

and no `Simulator_Project.launch`  file ...

I have tried refreshing the libraries, but to no avail. Maybe there have changes been made to the build process ...

How can I run the project?

[image]

Comment: What's the version of the Eclipse plugin? Can you make sure it's at the latest (currently 6.x)?

Assuming it's at the latest open Codename One Settings and do an "Update Project Libs".

Comment: The CN1 version is 6.0, and I did refresh the libraries. Still not wanting to run .... I believe the project is a restore from a backup. I don't know if this matters ...

Comment: Update project libs not refresh libs. Those are different things. The latter is done from within the settings app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant find any means to update the libraries. I couldn't find any button like in the post from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737652/updating-codename-one-in-eclipse/35737882#35737882 . See my screenshot, please.

Comment: The link is the old settings. In the screenshot above update is the 3rd button from the top in the right side menu

Comment: okay, I tried that ... project still won't execute ..

Comment: I'm stumped. I suggest creating a new project and just copying over the applicable files: src, res, codenameone_settings.properties, cn1libs and native.

Comment: Will do that... What about the Android signing/publishing key? Will this be copied, too? Otherwise, I won't be able to update the app in the Google Play Store,, right?

Comment: The path to the key is mentioned in codenameone_settings.properties so if it's the same path it should work.

Comment: Many thanks for your help ..